# (Number.MAX_VALUE + 2 ** 969) == Number.MAX_VALUE is true

Tags: javascript

Why does the following situation occur? Is the number 2**969 exactly a limit for this case?

```js
console.log((Number.MAX_VALUE + 2 ** 969) == Number.MAX_VALUE) // true
console.log((Number.MAX_VALUE + 2 ** 970) == Number.MAX_VALUE) // false
```

Comment: How long did it take you to find this special case?

Comment: `console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE - 2 ** 969); console.log(Number.MAX_VALUE - 2 ** 970);` shows the difference

Comment: @Pointy about 2 minute